# How to make auto width for columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having a row with columns.

And both row and css has the following properties.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f0f2f5
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="/">
   <div class="col"> 
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
     <span> ABC </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/">
   <div class="col">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
     <span> DEF </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <div class="col"> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
    <span> View All Applications </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Issue here is that the first two columns doesn't occupy the width of last column automatically. It leads to more space after first and second column and also width of third column is higher than first and second.

Requirement:

Requirement is how to make all the three columns of **equal space and width** using flex properties?

Tried using `flex: 1` to the column but it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to keep the same structure, either all of them have links or not. Your actual structure is not homogeneous

Comment: @TemaniAfif, The reason I use anchor tag on first two is that it leads to another url on click. Whereas the last column view all will make the opening of modal which will have all apps. So anchor tag is needed in first two and not in last.

Comment: @JoeFitzsimmons, It doesn't work as I have already mentioned in the question.

Comment: for the reason your code is failing making the col no more flex items

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Could you kindly guide me with right implementation for this?

Comment: I wouldn't tangle links up with your grid. You can accomplish exactly the same thing with the links _inside_ the columns, and then you can maintain separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1;` to your `.col` class. And also add flex to a tag as follows:

```
.row a{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f0f2f5
}
```

Check it here.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row a{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="/" style='background-color: blue;'>
   <div class="col"> 
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
     <span> ABC </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/" style='background-color: red;'>
   <div class="col">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
     <span> DEF </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <div class="col" style='background-color: green;'> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
    <span> View All Applications </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hsqt6z3w/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Will take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does actually a good job. The only thing thats "breaking" your widht is the text in your last div. If you want the width of each box being the same, then you can give your span another class, as an example, which contains:

```
.txt-wrap{
    width: 100px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

For word-break you need anything to break the words around. Does it makes sense?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f0f2f5
}

.txt-wrap {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="/">
   <div class="col"> 
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
     <span> ABC </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/">
   <div class="col">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
     <span> DEF </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <div class="col"> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
    <span class="txt-wrap"> View All Applications </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A `span` doesn't respond to width with its default display of `inline`.   Your example still shows uneven columns.

Comment: I didnt fix the original problem. I only mentioned the reason for this issue and an opportunity to fix it. I think everyone can copy and paste the view lines of code and word-break will do its magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent flex from growing one of your columns, then you can control the width of each element in the flex-box.  Since your `span` is causing an overflow, git it a display of `inline-block` (span is `inline` by default, which doesn't accept a `width` property), and then give it a max-width of your desired column width. This will make flex give your columns equal width automatically.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f0f2f5
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="/">
   <div class="col"> 
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
     <span> ABC </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/">
   <div class="col">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
     <span> DEF </span>
   </div>
  </a>
  <div class="col"> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="placeholder" />
    <span> View All Applications </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to have more white pace in between. May be something like @Boky's solution.